# Why can't you create/open multiple instances of iTunes?

Tags: itunes, terminal

In terminal, the `open -n ~/Applications/iTunes` doesn't create a new instance of iTunes, just switches to the one already open.  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes uses a database file to maintain a track of all the meta data on the contents of the iTunes library.  Opening multiple instances of iTunes would potentially result in the 2nd instance being unable to gain the correct access to these files as they would be locked by the first instance.

OK, you can have multiple iTunes libraries (hold Option when starting to choose or create a new one), but this is a relatively edge case scenario, and even for users of this functionality, I cannot see many instances where it would be useful to have more than one open simultaneously.  Playing 2 files at once would sound awful, and if you want to copy from one to another, you can still gain access to the files directly through the finder.

Comment: and how does the OS restrict this?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment

Comment: It doesn't have to be the OS, could also be iTunes itself which determines it's already running when started a second time.

Comment: I was going to suggest that it was the presence of the `LSMultipleInstancesProhibited` key set to true in the Info.plist inside the application bundle, but iTunes doesn't appear to have that set. Launch Services may hard-wired to to look for the `com.apple.iTunes` `CFBundleIdentifier` and not allow a second instance. You could try changing that manually in a second copy of the app bundle to see if it allowed it to launch. But I'd make backup copies of your library database beforehand. :-)

Comment: @stuffe I meant how does the OS restrict the user from opening a second instance.

Comment: @FrederickCraine I suspect it is application specific, nothing to do with the OS.  Some apps follow a document centric design (Pages/Textedit) some follow a window centric one (iTunes/SysPrefs).

Comment: @stuffe old answer, new comment. Running more than one instance of iTunes would be useful if you wanted to run several versions of iTunes, say, an iTunes X to maintain a music library and iOS5 devices, and iTunes 11 using a relatively empty library for a new iOS7 device that you had no intention of syncing anything but info/bookmarks/apps/books to. If you're up to it, and I understand if you're not (I know you can get busy!), but if so, I'd like to pick your brain about this idea I've just described. idk how to contact you otherwise... I'll be logged in a while, lets chat about it. Thank you.